# str_replace with a bunch of code php

Tags: php, string, forms, replace, str-replace

I have some content coming from database. And I want to replace the specific word of the content with a bunch of code.

Content coming from database is for example:

> Thank you for interest on our web site.
>   {FORMINSERT}
>   You can
>   also contact us by calling us to 1234567890

I want to replace the string `{FORMINSERT}` with a bunch of PHP code. If it is a normal text string I can simply replace it by using `str_replace`.

But the replacing content is not simple text it is form code.

want to replace this `{FORMINSERT}`

with example:

```
<form method="post" id="form1" action="<?php echo KT_escapeAttribute(KT_getFullUri()); ?>">
    <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2" >
        <tr>
            <td width="84" ><a name="contact" id="contact"></a></td>
            <td width="384">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" ><h1>Contact Us</h1></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td ><label for="fullname">Name:</label></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" value="<?php echo KT_escapeAttribute($row_rsscotts_contact['fullname']); ?>" size="47" />
                <?php echo $tNGs->displayFieldHint("fullname");?> <?php echo $tNGs->displayFieldError("scotts_contact", "fullname"); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td ><label for="phone">Phone:</label></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="<?php echo KT_escapeAttribute($row_rsscotts_contact['phone']); ?>" size="47" />
                <?php echo $tNGs->displayFieldHint("phone");?> <?php echo $tNGs->displayFieldError("scotts_contact", "phone"); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="email">Email:</label></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo KT_escapeAttribute($row_rsscotts_contact['email']); ?>" size="47" />
                <?php //echo $tNGs->displayFieldHint("email");?> <?php echo $tNGs->displayFieldError("scotts_contact", "email"); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="tellus">Looking for:</label></td>
            <td>
                <textarea name="tellus" id="tellus" cols="37" rows="5"><?php echo KT_escapeAttribute($row_rsscotts_contact['tellus']); ?></textarea>
                <?php echo $tNGs->displayFieldHint("tellus");?> <?php echo $tNGs->displayFieldError("scotts_contact", "tellus"); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" name="KT_Insert1" id="KT_Insert1" value="Submit" class="button-blue" /> 
                <input name="Reset" type="reset" value="Reset" class="button-grey" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: That `<form>` block you have shown above _is_ a simple text string. It is not PHP code that requires evaluation.

Comment: He wants to replace some PHP functionality with it! @MichaelBerkowski

Comment: Does your `<form>` actually contain any PHP inside `<?php ?>`? If it does, please post an example.  Otherwise, this can be done with `str_replace()`.

Comment: Yes, the form having some php code also. I have update the question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: OMG Dreamweaver + Interkt extension :) reminds me of the bad old days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

test1.php:

```
$database_content = 'Thank you for interest on our web site.
{FORMINSERT}
You can also contact us by calling us to 1234567890';

if(stripos($database_content, '{FORMINSERT}') !== FALSE){
    ob_start();
    include 'test2.php';
    $result = ob_get_clean();
}

$database_content = str_replace("{FORMINSERT}", $result, $database_content);

echo $database_content;
```

test2.php (the code you're trying to insert in):

```
echo 'hello world';
```

The result:

> Thank you for interest on our web site. hello world You can also
>   contact us by calling us to 1234567890

So it is as if the code "echo 'hello world';" was sitting right where {FORMINSERT} was.  You can just create a bunch of PHP files to include like that, and make some if statements to handle the replacements.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ob_start()`](http://www.php.net/ob_start) if you want to have HTML and PHP code combined and save the output inside one variable:

```
ob_start();
?>
    <form action="contact.php" method="post">
    Few fields here
    and submit button
    </form>
<?php

$forminsert = ob_get_clean();
```

Then you can do your `str_replace()` as per normal.

However, if the `{FORMINSERT}` may or may not appear, you could use `preg_replace_callback()` to reduce the cost of generating the form data in the case there's no need for it:

```
$content = preg_replace_callback('/{(.*?)}/', function($match) {
    if ($match[1] == 'FORMINSERT') {
        // code to generate $forminsert
        return $forminsert;
    }
    return $match[0];
}, $content_from_db);
```

Btw, this function can also be used more generically to replace anything between curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume the content comining from database you have is stored in variable `$db_content` & php code that you need to replace is in `custom_code.php`so

```
if(strpos($db_content, "{FORMINSERT}") === true){
    //remove the tag
    str_replace("{FORMINSERT}", '',$db_content)
    //load the php code
   require_once("custom_code.php")
}
//if need, you can add more conditions using else-if & replace more tags.
```

But its better to move towards `MVC` pattern where you can do such work easily via templates. Here is an [example](https://github.com/gaurish/PHP-MVC-framework-Boilerplate) I use for simple scripts

Comment: That won't put the contents of custom_code.php into where {FORMINSERT} was located, so that won't work.  I'll be posting a comment in a second that does what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

just do this and your work is solved

```
       $forminser= " welcome to our website {FORMINSERT}";
       $form= "<form action='contact.php' method='post'>
                 Few fields here
                and submit button
              </form>" ;
       echo str_replace("{FORMINSERT}",$form,$forminser);
```

EDIT>
if you want the php code inside your form then here an exemple

```
     $var = "Few words here" ;
     $forminser= " welcome to our website {FORMINSERT}";
     $form= "<form action='contact.php' method='post'>";
     $form .= $var ;  // this php code here
     $form .= "  and submit button</form>" ;
         echo str_replace("{FORMINSERT}",$form,$forminser);
```

edit2

here comes the whole code zou can make it.

```
    <?php

 $forminser= " welcome to our website {FORMINSERT}";
 $form = "<form method='post' id='form1' action=' " ;
 $form .=  KT_escapeAttribute(KT_getFullUri()); 
 $form .= " '><table cellpadding='5' cellspacing='2' >
         <tr>
         <td width='84' ><a name='contact' id='contact'></a></td>
         <td width='384'>&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
         <td colspan='2' ><h1>Contact Us</h1></td>
         </tr>
          <tr>
          <td ><label for='fullname'>Name:</label></td>
          <td><input type='text' name='fullname' id='fullname' value=' " ;

$form .= KT_escapeAttribute($row_rsscotts_contact['fullname']); 
$form .= " ' size='47' /> ";
$form .= $tNGs->displayFieldHint("fullname");
$form .= $tNGs->displayFieldError("scotts_contact", "fullname"); 
$form .= "</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
         <td ><label for='phone'>Phone:</label></td>
         <td><input type='text' name='phone' id='phone' value= ' " ;
$form .= KT_escapeAttribute($row_rsscotts_contact['phone']);
$form .= " ' size='47' /> ";
$form .= $tNGs->displayFieldHint("phone");
$form .= $tNGs->displayFieldError("scotts_contact", "phone"); 
$form .= '</td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><label for="email">Email:</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" value=" ' ;
$form .= KT_escapeAttribute($row_rsscotts_contact['email']);
$form .= '" size="47" />';
$form .=  $tNGs->displayFieldError("scotts_contact", "email"); 
$form .= '</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
         <td><label for="tellus">Looking for:</label></td>
          <td><textarea name="tellus" id="tellus" cols="37" rows="5"> ';
$form .=  KT_escapeAttribute($row_rsscotts_contact['tellus']); 
$form .= '</textarea> ';
$form .= $tNGs->displayFieldHint("tellus");
$form .=  $tNGs->displayFieldError("scotts_contact", "tellus"); 
$form .= '</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
         <td><input type="submit" name="KT_Insert1" id="KT_Insert1" value="Submit"  class="button-blue" /> <input name="Reset" type="reset" value="Reset" class="button-grey" /></td>
       </tr>
     </table>
    </form>
     ';

   echo str_replace("{FORMINSERT}",$form,$forminser);
 ?>
```

Comment: He already said it works fine for regular strings like that, he wants to replace it with PHP code.

Comment: Yes, some thing similar. But it won't work as it breaks the code. I have updated the example in question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: If not this please share your code with php tags and we will see how to fix it

Comment: @goodmood: Thank you for your effort. After reviewing your code. Yes it seems to be perfect and it should work. Thanks! but this code is too much time conservative and increases the line of code.Thank you for your solution. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, how about this one. The code below allows you to define custom {words} inside your content and they'll be replace with other content upon parsing.

```
$contentFromDB = "Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. {FORMINSERT}";

echo matchTags($contentFromDB);


function matchTags($content) {
   $pattern = '/{(\w+)}/i';
   $content = preg_replace_callback($pattern,"transformTags",$content);
   return $content;
}


function transformTags($word) {

    if ($word[1] == "FORMINSERT") {

        ob_start();
        ?>
        <form action="contact.php" method="post">
        Few fields here
            and submit button
        </form>
        <?php 
        $content = ob_get_clean();
        return $content;
    }

    if ($word[1] == "somethingelse") {

    }

}
```